# How can I un-init a folder I already initialized with the Git Shell on my PC?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-init

I created a "Projects" folder where I have all my web dev projects. I used `git init` on the folder before creating subfolders, which I also used the `git init` command for.

Now I want to treat them independently. How do I un-init the "Projects" folder that houses the other folders where my projects are?

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the .git folder in the folder where init was called.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, git doesn't have an "uninit" command. You could, however, just remove the `.git` folder that `git init` created. E.g., in *nix systems:

```
~/Projects$ rm -rf .git
```

Answer (score 0):

Using windows command line requires rmdir and other syntax:

> rmdir /s .git

C:\Users\username\Projects> rmdir /s .git

Windows cmd line code to remove a directory, which in this case is the errantly placed - and hidden - git directory. Hidden directories start with a period (".") as shown above.

Add /s to allow removal despite the directory having sub-files and/or sub-directories.